# How to show an image from a DataGridView to a PictureBox?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, bitmap

I'm trying to show an image in my DataGridView in a PictureBox.
I'm using SQL Server as database.

```
Me.PictureBox2.Image = DataGridView2.Item(10, i).Value
```

I'm wondering what code I am using.

This is the error says:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.Drawing.Image'.
```

Comment: Never post a question without telling us what actually happens when you execute the code you currently have. Post ALL the relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the Blob field Byte array (now a `DataGridView` cell Value) to an `Image` object.

A [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream) can be used to collect the Byte array and become the `Stream` source for the [Image.FromStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream) method.

```vb
If DataGridView2(10, 1).Value Is Nothing Then Return
Using ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(CType(DataGridView2(10, i).Value, Byte()))
    PictureBox2.Image?.Dispose()
    PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
End Using
```